# Proving $n$-th term formula of Fibonacci sequence using generating function

Tags: generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers

I am trying to get the formula $F_n = \frac{\phi^n - \psi^n}{\phi - \psi}$ using generating functions. I managed to find that $G_F(x) = \frac{1}{1 - x - x^2}$ then I used [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) to find that $$G_F(x) = \frac{1}{\phi - \psi} \Biggl(\frac{1}{x - \psi} - \frac{1}{x - \phi}\Biggr)$$

After that I took the following steps to simplify:
$$G_F(x) =  \frac{1}{\phi - \psi} \Biggl(\frac{\frac{1}{\psi}}{\frac{x}{\psi} - 1} - \frac{\frac{1}{\phi}}{\frac{x}{\phi} - 1}\Biggr)$$

$$ =  \frac{1}{\phi - \psi} \Biggl(\frac{\psi}{\frac{x}{\phi} - 1} - \frac{\phi}{\frac{x}{\psi} - 1}\Biggr), since\ \psi = -\frac{1}{\phi}$$

$$ =  \frac{1}{\phi - \psi} \Biggl(\frac{\psi}{-\psi x - 1} - \frac{\phi}{-\phi x - 1}\Biggr)$$

$$ =  \frac{1}{\phi - \psi} \Biggl(\frac{\phi}{\phi x + 1} - \frac{\psi}{\psi x + 1}\Biggr) $$

The issue is that this function generates the series

$$a_n = \frac{\phi \cdot (-\phi)^n - \psi \cdot (-\psi)^n}{\phi - \psi}$$

Now, the $n + 1$ as the exponent is probably due to the fact that I started my series with $1$ instead of $0$.But I don't understand *why is my series so close yet false*.

Comment: Are $\times$ and $\ast$ supposed to mean something different?

Comment: @halrankard No, just thought that \times was the international standard

Comment: I don't necessarily mind $\times$ or $\ast$, but using both in the same expression (last displayed equation) suggests that they mean different things. Also, the third and fourth lines of the middle array appear identical...or am I having a blind spot?

Comment: @halrankard you were right on both your points. Just edited my question

Comment: $F_0$ is [conventionally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) $0$, not $1$. So your $G_F(x)$ has to be multiplied by $x$ to accomodate.

Comment: @metamorphy wouldn't just replacing the n from the original formula by n+1 solve the issue?

Comment: Next question: In your PFD for $G_F(x)$ are you sure about the denominators inside the brackets? I get $x+\phi$ and $x+\psi$....

Comment: @halrankard Well I think that $1 - x - x^2 = -(x - \phi)(x - \psi)$. If we move the -1 to the nominator, denominators should be $x - \phi$ and $x - \psi$,

Comment: If $\phi$ and $\psi$ mean what I think they mean then the roots of $x^2+x-1$ are $-\phi$ and $-\psi$

Comment: @halrankard Yes. You are right. This was probably my mistake. Please give me 15 minutes to check it

Comment: @halrankard Yes indeed. This was my mistake. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @halrankard, I found out that I messed up with the sign of the constants here. In my solution, $\phi_{wrong} = -\phi$ and $\psi_{wrong} = -\psi$. Replacing $-\phi$ by $\phi$ and $-\psi$ by $\psi$ in the final formula yields:

$$ F_n = \frac{-\phi * \phi ^ n - (-\psi * \psi ^ n)}{-\phi - (-\psi)} $$
$$ = \frac{\psi ^ {n + 1} - \phi ^ {n + 1}}{\psi - \phi} $$
$$ = \frac{\phi ^ {n + 1} - \psi ^ {n + 1}}{\phi - \psi} $$

Note that the $n + 1$ in the exponent comes from the fact that I ignored the term $F_0 = 0$ when computing my generating function

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use exponential generating functions. Start with $F_{n + 2} = F_{n + 1} + F_n$, $F_0 = 0, F_1 = 1$. Define:

$\begin{align*}
   \widehat{F}(z)
     &= \sum_{n \ge 0} F_n \frac{z^n}{n!}
\end{align*}$

Now you see that:

$\begin{align*}
   \frac{d}{d z} \widehat{F}(z)
     &= \sum_{n \ge 0} F_{n + 1} \frac{z^n}{n!}
\end{align*}$

Take the recurrence, multiply by $z^n / n!$, sum over $n \ge 0$ and recognize the resulting sums:

$\begin{align*}
   \sum_{n \ge 0} F_{n + 2} \frac{z^n}{n!}
      &= \sum_{n \ge 0} F_{n + 1} \frac{z^n}{n!}
            + \sum_{n \ge 0} F_n \frac{z^n}{n!} \\
   \frac{d^2}{d z^2} \widehat{F}(z)
      &= \frac{d}{d z} \widehat{F}(z) + \widehat{F}(z)
\end{align*}$

As initial values you know:

$\begin{align*}
   \widehat{F}(0)
     &= F_0 = 0 \\
  \widehat{F}'(0)
     &= F_1 = 1
\end{align*}$

The traditional ODE dance tells you:

$\begin{align*}
   \widehat{F}(z)
     &= c_1 \exp(\phi z) + c_2 \exp(\psi z)
\end{align*}$

Using the initial conditions gets you:

$\begin{align*}
   F_0
     &= 0
      = c_1 + c_2 \\
   F_1
     &= 1
      = c_1 \phi + c_2 \psi
\end{align*}$

From the first equation we get $c_2 = - c_1$, we also know $\psi = 1 - \phi$:

$\begin{align*}
   1
     &= c_1 \phi - c_1 (1 - \phi) \\
   c_1
     &= \frac{1}{2 \phi - 1} \\
     &= \frac{1}{\phi - \psi} \\
   c_2
     &= - \frac{1}{2 \phi - 1} \\
     &= \frac{1}{\psi - \phi}
\end{align*}$

Extracting coefficients then gives:

$\begin{align*}
   F_n
     &= \frac{\phi^n - \psi^n}{\phi - \psi}
\end{align*}$

(Not that world-shattering here, but a useful trick if your recurrence has factors $n$ thrown in).